# where is the repository for yum in Fedora 15 (beta)?

Tags: fedora, yum

I just installed a pre-GA version of Fedora 15 and yum repolist is OK
I want to install software via yum. yum can find the desired package, but when downloading, yum reports HTTP Error 404 Not Found for all mirror list. I checked then found there is no repository for Fedora 15 at all. For example, the download ling points to 'http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/15/Everything/i386/..., but there is no '15' under releases.

Should I wait until Fedora 15 released in May 24? Is there any workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Google search:

> http://marcofalchi.blogspot.com/2011/03/fedora-15-fedorarepo-how-to.html

Since Fedora 15 is still in beta, not all mirrors have the repository up and running.

[This one](http://fedora.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/fedora/linux/development/15/) seems to have all the stuff you need.